# python groupby column and then getting any false value in each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

```
dff = (dff.groupby(["column 1", "column 2"]).first()) <br/>
print(dff)
```

gives table

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | a | true |
|  | b | false |
|  | c | true |
|  | d | false |
| second | a | true |
|  | b | true |
|  | c | true |
| Third | a | true |
|  | b | false |
|  | c | true |
|  | d | false |
|  | e | false |

above table was obtained by grouping 2 columns out of 3 columns

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | a | true | false |
|  | b | false |  |
|  | c | true |  |
|  | d | false |  |
| second | a | true | true |
|  | b | true |  |
|  | c | true |  |
| Third | a | true | false |
|  | b | false |  |
|  | c | true |  |
|  | d | false |  |
|  | e | false |  |

as shown above we want to have one more column with single value 
if any one of the values in column 3 ( at group level) has false , value should be false..else it should be true

pls help as i am stuck from 2 days

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) + [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html), as follows:

```
dff['column 4'] = dff.groupby(['column 1'])['column 3'].transform('min')
```

[`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) of a set of `True`/`False` values will give `False` if there is at least one `False` value.  Otherwise, it will give `True`.

**Data Input**

```
data = {'column 1': ['First', 'First', 'First', 'First', 'second', 'second', 'second', 'Third', 'Third', 'Third', 'Third', 'Third'],
 'column 2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 'column3': [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]}

dff = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['column 1', 'column 2'])


                   column3
column 1 column 2         
First    a            True
         b           False
         c            True
         d           False
second   a            True
         b            True
         c            True
Third    a            True
         b           False
         c            True
         d           False
         e           False
```

**Result:**

```
print(dff)

                  column 3  column 4
column 1 column 2                   
First    a            True     False
         b           False     False
         c            True     False
         d           False     False
second   a            True      True
         b            True      True
         c            True      True
Third    a            True     False
         b           False     False
         c            True     False
         d           False     False
         e           False     False
```

Comment: may be i am doing some thing wrong , but in my case groupBy  is no more effective , and getting same output as shiwn in initial question ..but yes new column 4 is being added with same values as shown for column 3 . Thankyou SeaBean for your efforts

Comment: @jatashankarshukla  If you really want to solve it, would you please dump the first few rows of your dataset so that I can check and give you the solution for it ?   Please dump your data of the first 5 rows by `dff.head(5).to_dict()` and add the dump at the end of your question as an edit.  I'll then look at it.

Comment: c1|dc|ch_1|true|p0
c1|jrs|ch_1|true|p0
c1|jtd|ch_1|true|p0
c1|phost|p_c|true|drwxrwx---.
c1|phost|p_c_d|true|jazz/jazz 
c1|phost|i_u|false|failed
c1|dc|f_p|true|-rwxr-xr-x.
c1|jrs|f_p|true|-rwxr-xr-x.
c1|jtd|f_p|true|-rwxr-xr-x.
c1|dc|m_f|false|absent
c1|jrs|m_f|false|absent
c1|jtd|m_f|true|prsnt
c1|dc|a_m|true|prsnt
c1|jrs|a_m|true|prsnt
c1|jtd|a_m|false|absent
c1|dc|s_f_p|true|-rwxrwx---.
c1|jrs|s_f_p|true|-rwxrwx---.
c1|jtd|s_f_p|true|-rwxrwx---.
c1|dc|u_s|true| p
c1|jrs|u_s|true| p1
c1|jtd|u_s|true|p2

Comment: @jatashankarshukla  As you are not generating the dump from the command `dff.head(5).to_dict()` I told you, it needs some more questions and answers here to clarify the data structure.  So, is it 5 columns instead of 3 ?   I don't seen the column names from your dump, so we call them `column 1`, `column 2`... ``column 5`  ?   `column 1` all have values `c1` ?    I'm afraid your data dump just differ a lot from the sample data you crafted for this question.

Comment: i am really sorry as i can see that you are keen to help, actually these data i cant share due to company policy , but you can consider this one to be correct data , my end goal is to get nested json object out of pipe separated text documents.
you can name column at your wish . also we need to do grouping of first 3 columns .Once again thank you for your prompt replies

Comment: @jatashankarshukla  Seen from your new sample data that the first 3 columns have quite distinct values. I mean if you group by the first 3 columns, then probably every group only have one element.   As a result, if we aggregate on this 1-element group on the 4th column which has True/False values, the result will be just the same as the original column value.   You see the point ?

Comment: so do i need to iterate programmatically to create new column , and during iteration i can mark value as false for any false present in group
SeaBean